# Why UserNotVerifiedException error is not trigered?

Tags: laravel-5, verification

In my my laravel 5.7.3 application I use https://github.com/jrean/laravel-user-verification extention and with use of
middleware I generate UserNotVerifiedException error when logged is not verified
But with excception I want to make logout and redirect to  /login page and reading https://laravel.com/docs/master/errors#the-exception-handler doc in
file app/Exceptions/Handler.php I do :

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Auth;
use App\Exceptions\UserNotVerifiedException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

use Jrean\UserVerification\Traits\VerifiesUsers;  // Do I need to add these declarations here ?
use Jrean\UserVerification\Facades\UserVerification;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    use RegistersUsers;
    use VerifiesUsers;
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        dump($exception);
        if ($exception instanceof UserNotVerifiedException) {
            dump("Make Logout");
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect('/admin/dashboard/index');

        }
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

In dump file I see first message, but not second(and why there is no redirection):

```
UserNotVerifiedException {#509 ▼
  #message: "This user is not verified."
  #code: 0
  #file: "/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/jrean/laravel-user-verification/src/Middleware/IsVerified.php"
  #line: 26
  trace: {▶}
}
```

Which is valid way ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using package ```jrean/laravel-user-verification``` ?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned it in topic description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to put the original namespace like:

```
if ($exception instanceof \Jrean\UserVerification\Exceptions\UserNotVerifiedException) {
    dump("Make Logout");
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect('/admin/dashboard/index');
}
```